# How do I do syntax highlighting in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

[image]

How do I display syntax-highlighted HTML code like this picture from the VueJS documentation?

I have tried using `v-html` but I just get a console error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspecting the VueJS documentation code snips, you can see they contain the class `hljs`.

This class is used by [HighlightJS](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js), a simple framework for code syntax highlighting.

HighlightJS automatically detects the language based on the syntax and can be extended with custom themes and configurations.

To install it in your vue package simply run either `npm install highlight.js --save` or `yarn add highlight.js`.

Once installed, import it and register it as a Vue plugin `Vue.use(hljs.vuePlugin);`

You can then use the component within your Vue templates:

```
<div id="app">
    <!-- bind to a data property named `code` -->
    <highlightjs autodetect :code="code" />
    <!-- or literal code works as well -->
    <highlightjs language='javascript' code="var x = 5;" />
</div>
```

You can find the above Vue example [here in the documentation](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#using-with-vuejs).

Comment: Brother, actually I want to implement this inertia js + laravel project I use in Vue 3. but don't implement highlight.js. Have you any idea of that ?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Any errors or issues? It may be more helpful to create a new question as comments aren't for off-topic discussion

Answer (score 1):

You could just put out the sanitized string:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      script: `&lt;script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;`,
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Code:<br>
      <code v-html="script"></code><br>
    </div>
  `,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants to do. It seems like he wanted to know how the Vue documentation displays their code examples, which it does with syntax highlighting. See my answer for an example of the exact library VueJS documentation uses

Comment: @Jordan maybe - to me it's not totally clear from the question. "I use v-html but when I type script tag it shows an error". He might need a full library, but he might just want the error to "go away".

Comment: That's fair, honestly. I do notice now that he said he had an error with the `v-html`. Could be that too. My interpretation was that he wanted to mimic how VueJS displays their code. However, if he wants to display code it would definitely be more user friendly to also syntax highlight it - even if this wasn't his question to begin with.

Comment: thank you, brother. Both of you give me the answer. Sorry for my mistake. I actually want to know how the vue documentation shows their code in a document like a script tag which one describes by @Jordan

Thank you again, Jordan, muka.gergely

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @imnhasan. Make sure to mark my answer as the correct one so it gets more visibility to help others with a similar question and please leave a comment if anything isn't clear enough :)

Comment: thank you brother your process also give me right direction. @muka.gergely

Comment: @imnhasan I hope that my answer helped you in some way. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use vue 3 I recommend you to use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-code-highlighter

It's a modern vue syntax highlighter made by me :)

Comment: show how to use it.

Comment: you can read at their documentation

Comment: you can read this community's guidelines https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587